# IOS 8 / 7 unique user identifier

Tags: xcode

As of IOS8 and IOS7 is there any way to retrieve a unique id for each user of my app? I really need to identify every user of my app and register on a database in order to have some statistics but how can I do it?

Comment: No there is no-way and against the privacy statement of Apple to be able to track devices.

Comment: There is a vendor id. You could use this. Another approach could be to generate an ID on your server and fetch it in the app.

Comment: @rckoenes This is not true.

Comment: Vendor ID is not bound to the device, if the user removes all de vendor apps and reinstalls then you will have a new vendor ID. Also read Apples privacy statement!

Comment: @dasdom can you explain how vendor id works please? And also, is it unique for every device? (No problem if the user uninstall and reinstall the app)

Comment: When I typ "vendor id iOS" into the search engine of my choice I get more than 2,000,000 results. :) Try it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UUID.Its important to save UUID in NSUserDefault once generated because UUID will be different for each generation.

```
+ (NSString*)getAppUUID
{
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *uuid = [userDefaults objectForKey:NSLocalizedString(@"DeviceToken",nil)];

    if(!uuid)
    {
        CFUUIDRef uuidRef = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
        CFStringRef uuidStringRef = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuidRef);
        CFRelease(uuidRef);
        uuid = (__bridge NSString *)uuidStringRef ;

        [userDefaults setObject:uuid forKey:NSLocalizedString(@"DeviceToken",nil)];
        [userDefaults synchronize];
    }

    return uuid;
}
```

To generate UUID,you can use below method also from iOS 6

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice]identifierForVendor]
```

Comment: To code you post will create a new `UUID` every time, thus it is not complete answer to the users question.

Comment: I would suggest storing it in the KeyChain so it becomes persistent.

Comment: In your pre-iOS 6 UUID code sample, you should use `__bridge_transfer` or `CFBridgingRelease`, not `__bridge`.